# Core data fetch request with NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm using this code for fetch data from `core data`

```
    NSFetchRequest * desFetctRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [desFetctRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"IssueDescription" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    [desFetctRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
    [desFetctRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(issueId == %@) && (partyId == %@)",issueId, pid]];
   NSError * error = nil;
    NSArray * savedIssuesDes = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:desFetctRequest error:&error];
```

but i get `savedIssuesDes` array with 0 object, however if i don't use predict than it gives me `savedIssuesDes` with 7 objects.
i got the value of predicate as `issueId == "42" AND partyId == "1"` 
**Is there any problem with my predicate?**
however i used `NSPredicate` like that in my other project and i got expected results.

**EDIT:** here is my `IssueDescription` class

```
@interface IssueDescription : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * desriptionId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * issueDesc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * issueId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * partyId;

@end
```

**Solutions:** As every one saying, every thing was Ok here.`partyId` is changed to `party_id` on server side. I wish that guy be in front of me.Anyway Thanks every one for your help.

Comment: Just asking the obvious: Have you triple-checked that there is an object with the given issueId/partyId combination?

Comment: Could you provide IssueDescription in xcdatamodel?

Comment: The predicate looks fine and I cannot see an obvious error. Perhaps the stored issueId/partyId contain some leading or trailing spaces or newline characters? - What happens if you fetch all objects (without a predicate)  and then filter the resulting *array* with the predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine to me but you could do it this way as well.

I prefer this as it makes it easier to read (for me anyway).

Just wanted to point out another way you could try it that might make it easier to debug...

```
NSFetchRequest * desFetctRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"IssueDescription"];

[desFetctRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

NSPredicate *issuePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"issueId = %@", issueId];
NSPredicate *partyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"partyId = %@", pId];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubPredicates:@[issuePredicate, partyPredicate];

[desFetctRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *savedIssuesDes = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:desFetctRequest error:&error];
```

Once you've done this try changing the compound predicate to only have one predicate each just to make sure your model includes the correct data.

Comment: Thanks man you saved me by saying **Once you've done this try changing the compound predicate to only have one predicate each just to make sure your model includes the correct data** partyId was changed in response dictionary from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
[desFetctRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(issueId = %@) && (partyId = %@)",issueId, pid]];
```

or

```
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(issueId == '%@') && (partyId == '%@')",issueId, pid];

[desFetctRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format]];
```

Comment: Creating the predicate string with `stringWithFormat` is a bad idea. It fails if any of the parameter strings contains quotation marks or other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove `[desFetctRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];`
.

> If includesPropertyValues is NO, then Core Data fetches only the object ID information for the matching records—it does not populate the row cache. Core Data still returns managed objects since it only needs managed object IDs to create faults. However, if you subsequently fire the fault, Core Data looks in the (empty) row cache, doesn't find any data, and then goes back to the store a second time for the data.

[Apple docs link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/includesPropertyValues)

Answer (score -1):

you have to replace && by AND

Edit: Martin is right

Edit2: Did you try with = instead of ==. If you use ==, try with '%@' in your Predicate

Comment: This is not correct. Both `&&` and `AND` can be used in a predicate, they are completely equivalent.

Comment: Sorry for complaining again, but `=` and `==` are also equivalent in a predicate. And `'%@'` is definitely wrong, because `%@` will not be expanded inside quotation marks.

Comment: yes, i have to create a format first then use it as parameter of predicatewithFormat. I don't have a Xcode example here to verify but I usually use NSPredicate as: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute1 = %@ AND attribute2 = %@",value1, value2]; when value1 and value2 are NSString.